# How to apply different styles to an <ion-list> where each element is created in JS with concatenation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

I am creating a list in my html as follows:
`<ion-list id="review-list"></ion-list>`

This comes from my JavaScript file (I am using vanilla JS in Ionic-framework):

```
const reviewList = document.querySelector('#review-list');

// There is code here in between with the event listener

const newItem = document.createElement('ion-item');
newItem.textContent = enteredName + ' - ' + enteredRating + '/5';
reviewList.appendChild(newItem);
```

I need to make bold only the portion of `enteredName`, how can I style each portion differently? As it goes as a single element to html.

Thank You!

I tried:
`<p style="font-weight: bold"><ion-list id="review-list"></ion-list></p>`

But this did not work, plus, is not actually what I need because this would make bold the entire text in the component, and I need only a portion of it in bold.

Answer (score 0):

Update: this can be done using .innerHTML and then concatenating strings with '+'